# Do I need to re-make and re-install couchdb everytime I want to test a change to the source?

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I am trying to contribute more with couchdb code, but I have really no idea how it is done the right way.

I have cloned the source from apache git repository and built it with

```
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

Then I wanted to change a file from the source called `couch_httpd_show.erl`

Do I need to run `make && sudo make install` again for every change I make to the source code and want to see how it behaves?

I am sure there's a more practical way to do it, because this approach is a bit time and patience consuming right?

Comment: Hehe manojlds, you removed the git tag like 20 seconds before I got the chance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a shortcut.

```
./configure
make dev
./utils/run
```

This builds and runs CouchDB entirely in the current directory. Instead of running as a background daemon, CouchDB will run in the foreground and output log messages to the terminal. It uses some local directories to store stuff: `./tmp/log` for logs, `./tmp/lib` for databases, and (if I remember correctly) `./etc/couch/local_dev.ini` for configuration.

If you run this instead:

```
./utils/run -i
```

then you will also have an interactive Erlang prompt, which you can use to help debug.

When I work on CouchDB, I run this in the shell:

```
make dev && ./utils/run -i
```

After I change some code, I press `^C`, up-arrow, return.

When I joined Couchio, I was responsible for production CouchDB deployments. I asked Chris Anderson for advice about something and he said, "Sorry, ask Jan. I've been just using utils/run for years!"

Comment: that's really convenient @jhs, thanks so much for this, it really helps out. it is fantastic you don't even have to install it. cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can rebuild that one file and drop the output beam in place and restart.

Comment: thanks Dustin, would you mind to describe how to do it please? I am really new to this, sorry for my lack of knowledge. thanks again :)

Comment: I have heard of people using essentially that technique to upgrade couchdb in production.

Answer (score 0):

```
erlc <file.erl>
```

& then copy the .beam file into place. To restart couchdb use either init:restart(). in the erlang shell or POST /_restart to CouchDB.

Although you might want to consider using the commandline erlang & javascript test suite also to ensure you didn't break anything.